# 40amp breaker running a 30 amp dryer

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I am purchasing a home and on the home inspection it says that the dryer is on a 40amp breaker.  It states that we need to change that to a 30 amp breaker to prevent over heating of dryer conductors.

Is that something that needs to be changed right away or is a 40 amp breaker fine?

Comment: What make and model is the breaker panel in question?

Comment: The overcurrent device is not protecting the dryer itself from overheating but protecting the conductors (wire) to the dryer from overheating. 

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this question depends mainly on two factors. It really has no bearing on the dryer itself.

1. The size (diameter) of wire conductors from the breaker in the panel over to where the dryer plug is located. The primary function of the panel breaker is to protect the wiring from ever being used at a current rating over its rated size. If that wire is 10AWG then the breaker needs to be a 30A breaker. 8AWG wire may be used with a 40A breaker.
2. The dryer plug outlet itself will be rated for a particular current carrying capability. If that is a 30A outlet then it cannot be used with a 40A breaker even if the wire was rated at 40A.

If the dryer outlet looks like this it is a 30A outlet and the breaker will definately need changing. When doing so just make sure that the connecting cable has at least 10AWG conductors. (Note that wires with smaller AWG numbers are larger diameter wires capable of higher current).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Change it now.**

The de-facto standard dryer receptacle is 30 amps.  Obviously, this requires a 30A breaker.  The usual wire in a dryer circuit is 10AWG. This requires a 30A breaker.

I don't know how a 40A breaker got on your dryer circuit, those are used for ranges and occasionally large air conditioners.

*(A 40A breaker would be ok on a 50A receptacle if the appliance is 40A, because that a special exception -- they don't make 40A receptacles.)*

Answer (score 1):

It is the wiring that needs to match the breaker.

If the wiring is rated for 40A (usually AWG8), you are good to go with a 30A appliance. Note that the plug may not match the receptacle BUT you can change either and it will be safe to run (if a bit confusing to a 3rd party so label your outlet/plug.)

If the wiring is rated for 30A (usually AWG10) then please change the breaker. It is a potential fire hazard. (Not urgent though, so long as you monitor your appliance - although by-the-book electricians will swear by their mom otherwise. A dryer in good order will not draw more than 30A, and a short will trip a 40A just as fast as it will trip a 30A. If your dryer malfunctions though...)

Comment: It’s a code violation to have a 30A receptacle on a 40A circuit, period (well maybe with some welder exceptions that don’t apply here). The mind boggles as to why you dug up a thoroughly answered question from six years ago to imply otherwise.

Comment: With all due respect, how can running a 30A appliance through 30A receptacle on a 40A circuit with a 40A breaker be "more unsafe" than plugging say a 5A grinder thru a 16awg extension cord into a normal 15A outlet? Please enlighten me. 

(And please don't keep saying "code violation" because much as it tries to sound intimidating, "to code === safe, not to code === unsafe" simply fails to stand up to reason. The simplest proof is grandfathering. Noting can be, from first principles, "safe in old homes but not in new homes" - yet many things are "to code in old homes but not in new homes".

Answer (score -2):

If you have a dryer that is rated for 30 A goes beyond 30 A you have a problem with the dryer. That’s why the breaker trips. If it is allowed to go past 30A, you getting to the danger zone. And I don’t mean the song from top gun. It is meant to trip to let you know there is a problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).